# how to write shell script to run update query and what does "<<" means?

Tags: shell, unix

```
mysql $DB_NAME <<EOFMYSQL
UPDATE environment  SET is_default = CASE WHEN environment='$ENV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
EOFMYSQL
```

i want to update run my update query is it correct code to run?
and what does << means in shell script why do we write EOFMYSQL after first line?

Answer (score 3):

The `<<` notation is a 'here document' and supplies standard input from the text in the script from the line after the line containing `<<` to the line consisting solely of the word specified after the `<<` (in your example, `EOFMYSQL`).  So, the one-line UPDATE statement is the standard input to the `mysql` command.

When you don't quote EOFMYSQL (as in your example, then shell variables are expanded in the here document.  If you quote it, then variables etc are left unexpanded.

If `$ENV` contains the value you're after, it should work.

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) this error comes when i call above function

Comment: So, you need to change the `mysql` invocation so that it gives a user name and maybe the password.  That's independent of the shell scripting.  Or, at least, largely independent of it.  You have to worry about how the script will read the password since the standard input is coming from the here document.  But, as I said, that is mostly independent of how the bit of shell script works.